# Lenovo 500s (8GB) vs Lenovo 510s(16GB)

Tags: laptop

I am wondering which Ultrabook should I choose.

1. Lenovo Ideapad 500s-13 i5-6200U/8GB/240SSD GF920M - Ram DDR3
2. Lenovo 510S i5-6200U 16GB 120SSD R5M430 - Ram DDR4

I would have to pay 10% more for the second one. I will be using it mostly for work, studying. For example photoshop, Android Studio, maybe some lite 3D work.

What do you think? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would get the 510s.  You can easily upgrade the SSD when you are ready, but for 10% more you not only get twice the memory but its DDR4 versus DDR3.